# read txt file into an adjacency matrix

Tags: java

I'm looking to read a text file that contains a matrix in this format:

```
1 2 3 4
1 3 1 4
1 5 5 1
1 1 1 1

dsadadasdasdasdasdasd
```

I would like to read the text file up until the blank line and ignore the rest of the text below.

I currently have this but not sure if I'm close. any help would be appreciated. thanks

```
matrix = new int[4][4];

        input = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
        String tempLine = null;

        while ((tempLine = input.nextLine()) != null)
        {
            if(!tempLine.isEmpty())
            {
                //System.out.println(tempLine);
                for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    String[] vals = tempLine.trim().split(" ");
                    for(int j=0; j < vals.length; j++)
                    {
                        matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(vals[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        input.close();
```

The ouput im currently getting is a 4 by 4 array containg the last row for each entry.

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

Comment: !tempLine.isEmpty()
May the line is not empty after your matrix.
There could be a linefeed. Linebreak.
Didn't code a long time with java.

Comment: i figured it out. thanks for the help

Comment: So what was the issue?